# How to detect SSL gracefully

Tags: java, http, ssl

I've got a web service which may be bound either to ssl or plain http. The java clients configured to know the server host and port. When client connects, I construct the server end point like http://host:port/service. Clients don't have a knowledge whether the server is using ssl - server always binds to a single port so that it's either secure or not. Now, the question is how to make a client to discover this without introducing another parameter? Can I challenge plain http request and then fall back to ssl (or vice verse) on a certain exception? Or I must explicitly introduce new connection parameter for the clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server side, you could use a mechanism like [Grizzly's port unification](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2006/11/07/one-tcp-port-to-rule-them-all/) implementation. This can be used to serve HTTP and HTTPS on the same port. This relies on the fact that in both cases, the client talks first and either sends an HTTP request or an SSL/TLS Client Hello message. It's quite handy for this on the server side (although I'm not sure I'd recommend running two protocols on the same port in general).

From the client's point of view (which is what you're asking about), the consequences of that are:

- The fact that the client talks first means that it will always have to try first. Expect an exception of some sort if you try to talk SSL/TLS to a plain HTTP service and vice versa.
- If the server uses port unification, there is no way you're going to be able to find out reliably.

Port unification aside (this is a rare case after all), you could try to cache results of past attempts.

**More fundamentally, from a security point of view, not knowing which protocol should be used introduces a vulnerability: your system will be open to downgrade attacks** (in a similar way as [blindly relying on automatic redirects](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628) would). If your user-agent supports [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), it would be worth looking into that (although it would require the user-agent to remember which sites are to be used with HTTPS).

Either way, if you're concerned about security, you **must** configure the client to know when to use `https://`.

Comment: This looks like something I am after. The security is a concern, otherwise there wouldn't be SSL in the first place. However, at this particular case it's not a big deal because all we need is to encrypt the traffic, authentication is not an issue. In fact, the client in this case is actually a server node which calls another node of the same kind (it's some kind of talk within a cluster). I just needed a nice short cut to avoid introducing a new parameter. Sounds like there is no reliable way of doing this, but I'll play around with port unification thingy, sounds interesting, thanks!

Comment: Authentication of the server (before encryption) is always an issue, unless you know for sure that you can at most have passive attackers (eavesdroppers) that won't be able to alter the traffic at all.

Comment: yep, that's the case, the eavesdroppers aren't a threat in my case