# Force 401 response with no https

Tags: apache, ssl

I set up mod_ossl directives in a virtual host (*:4444) to enable ssl on that particular port.

This works wonders when using https://example.com:4444, however when using http://example.com:4444 I get the ascii

```
NAK ETX SOH NUL STX STX
or
0x15 0x03 0x01 0x00 0x02 0x02
```

Would it be possible to force a 401 or something similar instead?

Comment: More or less a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10348370/372643).

Comment: It's not. I don't want to host anything on plain http, I want an error for the user and not a seemingly random series of bytes.

Comment: No, but you're trying to detect the protocol you're getting.