# Redirect HTTP traffic from 443 port to SSL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https, virtualhost

I've a site `www.example.com` that redirects HTTP traffic to HTTPS using RewriteEngine:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
    ....

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^example.com [NC]
    RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1  [L]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
    RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem I've found is that google has indexed this URL:

```
http://www.example.com:443
```

Giving this error:

[image]

I have tried to redirect the traffic adding a permanent redirection from both 80 and 443 virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^example.com [NC]
    #RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1  [L]
    #RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
    RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

without success. What's the right way to redirect all traffic from http://www.example.com:443 (and derived pages) to https://www.example.com?

Comment: That's more or less the same problem as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10348370/372643). The mistake here was to get `http://www.example.com:443` indexed in the first place. Do you know why this happened? Surely, if this is currently indexed by Google, this will eventually be removed from the index (especially once you've fixed whatever caused this).

Comment: No, I don't know how it happened. I've checked all links and none of them has a :443 port specification. All pointing to https. So I suppose it is linked from an outside source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the right way to redirect all traffic from http://www.example.com:443 (and derived pages) to https://www.example.com?

There is no such way:

- `http://www.example.com:443` means to establish a TCP connection to port 443 and then speak HTTP directly
- `https://www.example.com:443` means to establish a TCP connection to port 443, do a TLS handshake and then speak HTTP inside this TLS connection.

As you can see, both access use a TCP connection to the same port, but one is speaking HTTP to the server while the other TLS to the same server (same host and port means same server). While it would be possible in theory to distinguish between a HTTP request (for `http://...:443`) and the start of the TLS handshake (for `https://...:443`) and handle them separately such functionality is usually not supported by servers, because the usual way is to use port 80 for http and port 443 for https.

This means, that the server expects a TLS handshake at port 443. The server detects that it does not get the TLS handshake but a HTTP request instead and returns the "Bad Request" message to the client, explaining that it is the wrong kind of request to this port.

Comment: Yes, that's clear, thank you. But is sure I can do something to avoid this problem. For example, if I type http://mail.google.com:443 or http://www.facebook.com:443 in my browser, the webserver redirects to the corresponding https://website.com page.

Comment: @Ivan I suspect this is a side-effect of [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (which both these sites use). No plain HTTP message is actually sent on the network.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, the best I can do is to find which website has linked to http://www.example.com:443 and ask to change the link in order to avoid google crawling. Right?

Comment: @Ivan: yes.  And from the standpoint of a user or crawler it would be the same if a website would have linked to `http://example.com:12345` instead or to `http://example.com.something.wrong` - the user would not get to your site and would instead get some error message. The only difference is that you would probably not notice it on the server side.

Comment: Yes, I understand, the bad part is google indexing that bad link. Thanks.